# Server side validation is done with data annotations instead of doing client side validation

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, client-side-validation, server-side-validation

while I was working with validation in MVC, and I wrote a custom attribute to validate a property.Initially the client side validation was not working since attribute was not registered.When i clicked on the **`save`** 
 button *after contacting the server* it was showing the error message.So can anyone tell how this server side validation took place instead of client side validation ?

attribute usage ->

```
[PhoneNumberHasPlus(ErrorMessage="Invalid number")]
public string PhoneNumber {get;set;}
```

attribute ->

```
 public class PhoneNumberHasPlusAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
    {
        public PhoneNumberHasPlusAttribute() :
            base(@"^[+][0-9' '\.\-\(\)]{10,20}$") { }

        public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
                ErrorMessage = "PhoneNumberWithPlus";
            return ErrorMessage;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a Model.IsValid in your action. That element turns on the validation.

```
public ActionResult Create(Model model) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        // logic
    } 
    return View(dinner); 
}
```

Please make sure that your view contains correct path to jQuery libraries

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"></script>
```

Also your have to use this Razor syntax to generate correct html

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
```

[Here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model) you can find a full tutorial of adding validation to the MVC Model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jquery Val bundle into your view
like this

```
@section scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryVal")
}
```