# How to show custom data annotations at the same time as "required" annotation errors?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, validation

I've created my own data annotation for a list of objects and it works. But when I submit the form, the browser displays only the error messages for "required" properties without the page reloading.

If the "required" fields are filled, the browser then reloads the page and displays my custom error message.

I would like to show the error message for my custom property at the same as the "required" messages are shown. Is this possible?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34940878/server-side-validation-is-done-with-data-annotations-instead-of-doing-client-sid

Comment: How can we possibly see what error you have made if you do not show your code!

Comment: That was really usefull. Thank you.